# T-SQL query: where column not in is giving wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table A and table B, the common column in both table is Name, 
I want to know what are name in Table A that is not in table B

when I do:

```
Select Name from A where Name not in (Select Name from B)
```

I am sure there are 2 name in Table A that is not in table B

but the result returns nothing

These name column in table A and B has the same datatype `varchar(50)`

so I copy the result of Name column and Insert into a new table and do the same query, and this time it returns the right result. what bug could this be?

example:

```
Table A
Name:
Kevin
Dexter
David 
John
Marry

Table B
Name:
Kevin
Dexter
David
```

So the query should return `'John'`, `'Marry'` but it doesn't return in my original table, but it returns in another table I create and insert.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Marc_s for editing my post so it's more readable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have a `NULL` name on `B`, this makes the `NOT IN` false for every row. You should use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B 
                  WHERE A.Name = B.Name)
```

Comment: You are correct, I found a null value in this column, thanks a lot !

Comment: Brilliant!   Helped solve an almost midnight debugging session!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it is because of NULL value on some rows in table B. You can do what you want with `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT Name FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT Name FROM TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.Name = a.Name
WHERE b.Name IS NULL
```